# IntelliJ Local History for a file that was added and then removed

Tags: intellij-idea

Local History feature works great for a files that were just modified, but is it possible to see history for a file that was added and then mistakenly removed without commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your question was to get back the deleted files from the Intellij. As you said the local history provides the great features, the restoring of deleted files can also be done in the same by just right clicking and selecting the restore option. For more details [refer](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2008/01/using-local-history-to-restore-deleted-files/).